# conflict between twitter-bootstrap and HighCharts plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am using the twitter-bootstrap framework for few of its features such as tooltip, typeahead and datepicker.

I am also using `HighCharts` plugin to display charts on the same page.

But there seem to be some sort of conflict between the two. Bootstrap features stop working due to the HighCharts code and I get errors on console related to bootstrap:

```
TypeError: $("a[rel='tooltip']").tooltip is not a function
```

And when I remove the HighCharts code, bootstrap features comes up just perfectly fine.

So can anyone guide me to resolving this issue.

Am using following js files:
**HighCharts**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >    
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {                  

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Expenditure'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Months'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Expenditure',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' (local currency)';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: <?=json_encode($series);?>                       
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: can you post your highcharts code?

Comment: @c0deNinja added the highcharts code.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before Highcharts?

Comment: yes I am! do you think thats the reason!?

Comment: no... jQuery should be loaded first.  Did you restructure the highcharts files?  Because the `exporting.js` should be under `modules/exporting.js`.

Comment: well yeah i am just using the two above mentioned JS files for HighCharts and placed it in my JS directory where the other files are present. I wonder this would cause any issues! please elaborate why you think this can be the cause...

Comment: Well, culd you reproduce issue on jsFiddle? I have used Highcharts and Bootstrap without any issues. Maybe something wrong is with version 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I use Twitter bootstrap tooltips with HighCharts.  The approach is to add a class to all elements that we'd like to use the Twitter tooltips for and also to add the title attribute to the element containing the text desired in the tooltip.  In our case, we do this for chart legends and chart titles.  We use a mouseover event handler to set up the tooltips:

```
$(function () {
$.fn.tooltip.defaults.placement = "bottom";
$.fn.tooltip.defaults.delay = {
    show: 500,
    hide: 50
};
$.fn.tooltip.defaults.html = true;

//read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678755
$(document.body).delegate(".Tipsy", "mouseover", function (evt) {
    var elt = $(this).closest(".Tipsy");
    elt.removeClass("Tipsy").addClass("Tipsified");
    elt.tooltip(); //set up tooltip
    elt.tooltip("fixTitle"); //fix titles
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        elt.off("mouseleave.autotipify").tooltip("show");
    }, 500);
    //if the user moves out before tooltip shows
    $(this).on("mouseleave.autotipify", function (evt2) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

});
//clicking on a trigger should cause the tip to disappear
$(document.body).delegate(".Tipsified", "click", function (evt) {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```

});